# Altering Svelte stores from JS component with .set() not working for objects

Tags: javascript, svelte, sapper, svelte-store

I am kind of new to Svelte/Sapper and I am trying to update the Svelte store from a JS component.

Setting and getting the values is working fine **as long as they are regular variables with no "depth"/nested objects.**

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong, or if there is really no way of altering specific keys of an object without replacing the whole object.

---

Let me explain what I mean:

**`stores.js`**

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

export const ui_vars = writable({
    filter_extended: false,
    menu_extended: false,
    loading: { products: true }
})

export const simple_var = writable(false)
```

---

`**test.js**`

```
import { get } from 'svelte/store';
import { simple_var, ui_vars } from "../stores";

// WORKING
console.log(get(simple_var)); // false
simple_var.set(true); // alters the simple_var from false to true (as expected)
console.log(get(simple_var)); // true

// NOT WORKING
console.log(get(ui_vars)); // outputs the object as in store
ui_vars.filter_extended.set(true); // SHOULD ALTER the ui_vars.filter_extended from false to true, but throws Error instead, ERROR: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (intermediate value).filter_extended is undefined
console.log(get(ui_vars)); // should output the altered object
```

The erro:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (intermediate value).filter_extended is undefined
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong here?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.set` is a function that exists on a `writable`.

When you do `ui_vars.filter_extended` it will be `undefined` because `filter_extended` doesn't exist on a `writable`.

If you want to set `filter_extended` to true, I would do:

```
ui_vars.update(x => {
     x.filter_extended = true;
     return x;
});
```